# Error when using Facebook's PHP SDK to send notification

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm sending a Facebook notification using PHP but I've run into a problem I can't seem to solve with Facebook's docs.

The notification informs a person that their friend has beaten them in a game, This is the PHP code that sends the message:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php'; 

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{123456789}',
  'app_secret' => '{1a2b3c4d5f6g7h8i9j}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  ]);

//This is an array of ID numbers received from an Ajax post
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
//This the ID number of the sender of the notifications
$senderid = $_POST['senderid'];
echo $senderid;

    foreach($data as $d){
    $request = $fb->post('/'.$d.'/notifications', array( 'template' => '@['.$senderid.'] just beat you!'), '123456789|1a2b3c4d5f6g7h8i9j');
}    
?>
```

This code is taking an array of ID numbers (`$data`) and sending the notification to each one. The `senderid` is the ID of the sender, and according to the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications typing something like `@[12625234523] just beat you!` should automatically put the name of the person who owns that ID in place, so the notification should read something like "John Doe just beat you".

But this isn't working for me. I'm certain that the sender's ID is successfully being posted to the PHP file because it's appears in the console when I `echo $senderid`. And when I type in the sender's ID manually into the 'template' part of the request I'm getting the same error in the console. The error is:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookServerException' with message 'An unknown error has occurred.' in /home/mywebsite/public_html/Games/Barre/facebook-sdk-v5/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php:105
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/mywebsite/public_html/Games/Barre/facebook-sdk-v5/FacebookResponse.php(210): Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException::create(Object(Facebook\FacebookResponse))
>
> ## 1 /home/mywebsite/public_html/Games/Barre/facebook-sdk-v5/FacebookResponse.php(255): Facebook\FacebookResponse->makeException()
>
> ## 2 /home/mywebsite/public_html/Games/Barre/facebook-sdk-v5/FacebookResponse.php(82): Facebook\FacebookResponse->decodeBody()
>
> ## 3 /home/mywebsite/public_html/Games/Barre/facebook-sdk-v5/FacebookClient.php(225): Facebook\FacebookResponse->__construct(Object(Facebook\FacebookRequest), '{"error":{"mess...', 500, Array)
>
> ## 4 /home/mywebsite/public_html/Games/Barre/facebook-sdk-v5/Facebook.php(504): Facebook\FacebookClient->sendRequest(Object(Facebook\FacebookRequest))
>
> ## 5 /home/mywebsite/public_ht in **/home/mywebsite/public_html/Games/Barre/facebook-sdk-v5/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php** on line **105**

I'm sure that the array of IDs is working correctly, as everything works perfectly when I remove the `$senderid` from the message template. This isn't ideal though as I would like to tell the player who has beaten them, instead of giving them a message like "You've just been beaten." I would like to include the name of the sender in the message/template but the method given in the Facebook document above isn't working, maybe it's only possible to use the `@[12425232]` method when typing into Facebook's Graph API Explorer?

I'd really appreciate any help anyone could give me with this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all, you should properly _catch_ exceptions in your code, so that they don’t result in fatal errors. Secondly, that exception message sounds rather like there might be a general problem with connection to the API, and rather not as if it was specific to this particular request.

Answer (score 0):

Please use GET or REQUEST instead of POST for data and senderid

Comment: Hi @yagnesh, can you explain what's wrong with using the POST method? I'm sending data from Javascript to a PHP file so I'm using POST, what's wrong with that method?

Comment: Ok nw then you will use try and catch statement for getting what is wrong with you Like   try {  Notification Code }} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                                                        echo "<br />".$e->getMessage();
                                                } in your foreach